# Plotly reactive x axis date format

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, axis-labels

I am working with `ggplot2` and `plotly`. I want my x axis to react to the date range that is being displayed. So, if the user is looking at 1990 - 2015, I'd want the x axis to display years.

Now, when the user brushes and the plot adjusts to show the user, let say, 1990 - 1991, I want the x axis to display months.

I need help setting up the reactivity part of this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `scale_x_date` from `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput("SDates", label = ("Select range"), 
                 start="2006-01-01",
                 min=min(economics$date),max=max(economics$date), 
                 format="dd.mm.yyyy",
                 end = "2007-01-01"),
  plolytOutput("plot")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df<-reactive({
    economics[economics$date<input$SDates[2]&economics$date>input$SDates[1]]
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    brakes<-ifelse(as.numeric(difftime(input$SDates[2],input$SDates[1], units="days"))>365,"1 year","1 month")
    ldates<-ifelse(as.numeric(difftime(input$SDates[2],input$SDates[1], units="days"))>365,"%Y","%m-%y")

    p<-ggplot(df(), aes(x=date, y=unemploy))+geom_line()+
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = brakes, labels = date_format(ldates))
    ggplotly(p)
  })




}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```